# How to diagnose damp coming up through cracks?

Tags: mold

I'm suspecting that my flat may have a damp and mould problem coming up through cracks etc and into my airspace.  I definitely know in one room there is damp underneath the floorboards though I thought if its covered its ok.  However I didnt account for coming up through cracks etc.

I really dont want to go to the trouble of lifting floors and floorboards to see how extensive the problem is.  Would one have to lift floorboards to confirm there are damp toxins coming into the air or could I diagnose it without lifting floorboards.  If so how?  How would a surveyor do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you concerned about humidity? That can be measured but “toxins” you would need a kit to take air samples and send it in to a laboratory.

Comment: @EdBeal As a first step would humidity imply damp is present and so toxins must be present too?

Comment: No moisture is not inherently toxic or our ground water would kill us. Moisture can promote growths like fungi , mold but even those are rare to be toxic there are thousands of mold species I know I live in Oregon USA well known for slugs and mold, with that said very few are actually toxic some are even helpful.

Comment: @EdBeal Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology.  But mould in buildings can make people sick hence use of the word toxic.  Im trying to find out if that stuff is in my air.

Comment: does it smell like a basement? if not, you're fine.

Comment: Ok the toxins are not coming through the floor, moisture coming through the floor is clean, when the moisture mixes with dust , wood fiber , or things that fall off your shoes it is the growth that has the possibility of becoming a toxic mold well I guess unless your home is built on top of a old chemical dump but moisture by itself is not bad, it’s when it provides a way for things to grow that can’t happen without moisture. If you want to find toxins take an air sample of your bathroom these are usually full of nasties like fecal matter most toothbrushes have more germs than a toilet seat.